# UIButton causing crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is a very simple issue but I have no idea why it's happening. In my header file, I've declared a `UIButton *leftButton`. In the viewDidLoad method I do this `leftButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];`

Then in some other method I have:

```
    leftButton.frame=newFrame;
    leftButton.tag=i;
    [leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(leftButtonSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:leftButton];
```

However I keep getting a crash when the above method is called. Sometimes I get a message, other times it just crashes with no message. I can't really replicate any crash messages, now all I'm getting is just a general crash, but it kept crashing from weird issues such as [UIGestureRecognizer setFrame] is causing problems or [WebView setFrame] or something..for some reason it keeps thinking that leftButton is something else than a UIButton, but this is not the case. There is nothing else named leftButton in my entire project. Any ideas?

Comment: just in case that you really ruled out obvious kind of problems with some NSLogs - in cases like these where I get really confused by what is happening in Xcode I delete the DerivedData. sometimes Xcode doesn't even recompile my file even though it says it would - its worth a try... - just realized - you are most probably not using ARC - so it might well be a memory problem where the button gets lost

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first method is returning an autoreleased object, most likely it has been released by the time your second method is called. Either retain the button in the first method or use a retained property to hold on to it rather than an ivar.

Also, remember to release this in your dealloc method at the end.

Comment: How do I retain it in the first method?

Comment: leftButton=[[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];  typing on phone, no formatting, sorry!